# Android data transferring with Json issue

Tags: java, android, json

This is my json array creating with php.
I want to know bellow json array have correct syntax.
How to get the values withing android,because my sample code get some errors.

**THIS IS PHP SCRIPT FOR JSON ARRAY GENARATING**

```
public static function getCategory($_lgtime) {
        $con = JsonDataManip::connect();
        $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from " . _TABLE_CATEGORY . " where lgtime > ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($_lgtime));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $jsonArray['key'] = $row['key'];
            $jsonArray['name'] = $row['name'];
            $jsonArray['lgtime'] = $row['lgtime'];
            $json[] = $jsonArray;
        }
        return $json;
    }
```

**usage php :**

```
echo json_encode(JsonDataManip::getCategory('20140129184514895'));
```

**GENARATED JSON ARRAY**

```
[{
    "key":"1",
    "name":"Category 10",
    "lgtime":"20140129184514896"
    },
    {
    "key":"2",
    "name":"Category 9",
    "lgtime":"20140129184514896"
    },
    {
    "key":"3",
    "name":"Category 8",
    "lgtime":"20140129184514896"
    }]
```

**ANDROID JSON PARSER FUNCTION**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject  jsnArry = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsnArry.getJSONArray("");
                for(int i=0;i<jsnArry.length();i++){
                    Log.d("JSON PARSE",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    //contactList[i] =          
                }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**ERROR**

```
01-30 08:45:53.527: W/System.err(1507): org.json.JSONException: Value {"lgtime":"20140129184514896","key":"1","name":"Category 10"} at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: can't you return as an object instead of an array? eg. 
{
"result" : [your array]
}

Comment: I dont know how to do that,i am new to android and json.

Comment: Just a note - it might be your problem.  If the array contains only 1 element, I believe the returned JSON object will just be a JSON object, not a JSON array.

Comment: u don't need a lib for it, can be as easy as http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json, look at the php implementation. from your parser you are expecting an object first then read an array but in actual fact you are returning an array as the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script returns a JSON array, not a JSON object. You should update your Android code like so:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        for (int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("JSON PARSE", json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.w("JSON PARSE", "Failed to parse JSON!", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to return Json Object ? This is my php usage of above code 
`echo json_encode(JsonDataManip::getCategory('20140129184514895'));`

Comment: Why do you want to return a JSON object? You're returning an array (list) of objects. This makes sense. Returning an object in this case would not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your JSON string is valid, please use this link [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).
As far your error is concerned for your code, it clearly states that

```
type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

**Possible Solution (if you are using Gson)**

Your response from `ServiceHandler` would be a string. So convert that into a `JSONObject` and the pass that to `JSONArray`.

**Example**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(<responseString>);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray();
```

**Else**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(<responseString>);
String key = jsonObject.getJSONObject("key");
String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject("name");
String lgtime = jsonObject.getJSONObject("lgtime");
```

Then you can continue with your logic in the program.

Comment: `JSONObject  jsnArry = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
     JSONArray jsonArray = jsnArry.getJSONArray("");
     for(int i=0;i<jsnArry.length();i++){
      Log.d("JSON PARSE",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
      //contactList[i] =    
     }`

`01-30 09:19:16.256: W/System.err(1555): org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)`

Comment: If you are not keen on using `Gson` to parse your data you need not convert to JSONArray. You can retrieve all your required data from JSONObject itself. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{    "employees":[
    {
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Anna",
    "lastName":"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Peter",
    "lastName":"Jones"
    }
    ]
}
```

Your opening and closing braces are missing. that is not a valid json array, The above is a sample array format

Comment: `[{
    "key":"1",
    "name":"Category 10",
    "lgtime":"20140129184514896"
    },
    {
    "key":"2",
    "name":"Category 9",
    "lgtime":"20140129184514896"
    },
    {
    "key":"3",
    "name":"Category 8",
    "lgtime":"20140129184514896"
    }]`

is a valid JSON. Verified by JSONLint <http://www.jsonlint.com/>.